How do I make a unique value for the number of players under the team?
Dataset is based on this table on this wikipedia page. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NBA_Finals_Most_Valuable_Player_award
I am only using year (2000 and above), players and team. I want to add a column called 'Team MVPS' meaning how many finals mvps did the team get since 2000. For example, Spurs have won 4 championships since 2000 but there are only three finals mvps. So the value should be 3. It should be like this



Year
Team
Player
Team MVPS




2000
Lakers
Shaq
3


2001
Lakers
Shaq
3


2002
Lakers
Shaq
3


2003
Spurs
Duncan
3


2004
Pistons
Billups
1


2005
Spurs
Duncan
3


2006
Heat
Wade
2


2007
Spurs
Parker
3


2008
Celtics
Pierce
3


2009
Lakers
Kobe
3


2010
Lakers
Kobe
3


2011
Mavs
Dirk
1


2012
Heat
Lebron
2


2013
Heat
Lebron
2


2014
Spurs
Kawhi
3


2015
Warriors
Iggy
3


2016
Cavs
Lebron
3



Here is my code
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("NBA Finals MVP 2000.csv")
teams = df['Team'].unique()

for t in teams:
    td = df[df['Team'] == t]
    #print(td.head(6))
    t_count = 0
    for p in td['Finals MVP'].unique():
        t_count+=1
    print(t_count)

    df['Team MVPS'] = t_count

df.head(24)

However, the Team MVPS column is all 1. I don't know what I did wrong.

I just want to confirm if your Team MVP column is all correct some of the entries towards the end feel wrong, how do warriors and cavs have 3 team MVP's ? and should lakers not have 2 finals MVP's since its just Kobe and Shaq ?

Seems need df['Team MVPS'] = df.groupby('Team')['Player'].transform('nunique')

@jezrael was just going to suggest that but the numbers did not match and I was worried I was missing context

@KaranShishoo - yop, some values match, some not.

oh the cavs is just a typo whoops. That is just sample data. This data goes all the way to 2024. I just included 2000-2016. Lakers did win in 2020 and that's why the value of Lakers is 3.
